# If Beerus wiped out all of the dinosaurs, how are dinosaurs still present?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragonball-super

In Dragon Ball Z : Battle of Gods, Beerus claims that he went to Earth once and dinosaurs took a rude attitude with him, so he wiped them out.

[image]

But then we see that in the present DBZ timeline, there are still roaming dragons around.

[image]

And even in Battle of Gods:

[image]

Comment: It seems that this was never again addressed and was just overlooked by Toriyama

Comment: Related: If we evolved from monkeys, then why are there still monkeys?

Comment: @Steve-O Not at all related, because monkeys were never wiped out.

Comment: If you look at it the manga changed a lot from dragonbal, dragonball Z  to later.   First most of the people were human/animal hybrids, with a king as ruler of earth. Then without explanation all the hybrids were gone and only humans are further seen (and no intelligent dinosaurs any longer as in db, then later dinosaurs also disappeared,...)

Comment: Couldn't Beerus just be wrong about having exterminated them all?

Answer (score 2):

Akira Toriyama forgot about the dinosaurs. If you look at the manga, after the Saiyan Saga, no dinosaurs are drawn. Furthermore, not everything in the anime and movies is canon. There is a lot of filler, and some are later contradicted by Toriyama.